# Shortcut para comentarios de títulos en Python

Tags: python

Estoy buscando el shortcut que genere la siguiente estructura de #, muy útil para dividir distintas secciones dentro de un mismo script.

```
######################################################
# 
######################################################
```

Comment: Buenas,¿ podemos saber que IDE usas?

Comment: Actualmente estoy utilizando pycharm. Sé que ese shortcut existe seguro para Spyder ya que hace un par de años estuve trabajando con ello.